# Conditional rendering of wssuc:Welcome

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I would like to modify my master page(s) to only render the user's name if the user is accessing the site externally, and provide the full drop-down list of options if the user is logging in from our intranet.

I want to do this server-side rather than via javascript and/or css on the client. This is a SharePoint Designer site so no option to add/modify server controls.

FWIW, the jQuery solution looks like:

```
var host = window.location.hostname.toUpperCase();
if (-1 < host.indexOf("EXTERNALHOSTNAME")){
    $("[id$=_Menu_t]").replaceWith(function(){ return $("[id$=_Menu]", this).text(); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
To my knowledge there is no server-side way to do what you want unless you replace the Welcome Menu control with a custom usercontrol - which is what you state you cannot add.
However you can alter the masterpage around the control. You can use the asp.net control `<asp:LoginName />` with property `FormatString`.

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="{0}" />
```

This will display only the logged in users name. However because of your limitations, you still have to use javascript to switch between the asp.net control only and the WelcomeMenu control nonetheless.

---

Since you cannot add server controls and only can edit it through SharePoint Designer, you are locked to the client-side scripting.

First, you need a value which indicates that the user is accessing the site externally - most commonly recognizable by the URL e.g. if internally the URL is 'intranet' and externally it is 'company.intranet.com'.

When the indicator value is decided then you can start your client-site scripting.

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var internalHostName = "INTRANET";
        var currentHostName = window.location.hostname.toUpperCase();
        if (internalHostName == currentHostName ) {
            // Find the parent class which the Welcome menu resides in - luckily it is unique.
            $('.s4-trc-container-menu').remove(); // Remove it from the DOM.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, wondering if you missed the jQuery solution at the end of my post? I don't want to remove the user's name, just remove the drop-down menu functionality which my jQuery snippet does perfectly. The point of my post was to try to find a server-side solution, I already know how to take care of it in the browser.

Comment: @DavidClarke Ah, sorry, my bad. Please check my update.